# HTC BLE problems and kontakt.io beacons api

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon-android, kontakt.io

I wrote and app using kontakt.io  api and examples for beacons.

This app correctly work on Sony Xperia SP, but when I use different models of HTC smartphones (like HTC Desire 820) this app work really slowly (active time for scanning is 3 seconds, for passive scanning - 2 seconds).

If I use Bluetooth scanning on the HTC (via settings of smartphone) - I had same problems. Very slow work (slow scanning).

Can somebody explain, why is so? Maybe this problem is only on HTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Kontakt.io, although not as an Android developer

Unfortunately the biggest strength of Android, its openness and variety, is IMHO also a source of the weakness that you see right now. Different manufacturers use different Bluetooth chipsets, antennas, etc. in their devices. All of the possible combinations usually work in typical Bluetooth use cases, like connecting to Bluetooth speakers, keyboards, etc., but some of them fail when something more is required (e.g. scanning beacons).

In my experience latest Samsung flagships are pretty reliable, but e.g. OnePlus phones have a lot of problems with beacons. Similarly, Nexus 5 is one of the best Android phones when it comes to working with beacons, but Nexus 5X really struggles with detecting them. You've mentioned Sony Xperia SP, that it works OK, but we had Xperia Z (don't remember the exact model, sorry) and it was horrible. Apparently your HTC falls into the *Bad BLE* category :-(

Comment: Thanks a lot! Some sources talk about the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a prioprietary software, so you should ask Kontakt SDK developer.

From my side I would suggest a following thing: check Android version system both devices operate on. BLE Android API was introduced in Android 4.3 and got huge refactor in Android 5.0. So this maybe the case of slow scanning.

Also take into consideration, that BLE devices do not broadcast their presence all the time, as one of their purposes is very low battery usage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All smartphones have Android 6.0 version. As I said before, this problem exist only on HTC smartphones.